# ipython on Windows 7 can't find pyreadline

Tags: python, windows-7, ipython

I am trying to install Ipython for Python3 on Windows 7.

installed Python3 using python-3.3.0.amd64.msi

installed pyreadline using pyreadline-1.7.1.win-amd64.exe

Downloaded distribute-0.6.34.tar.gz

Downloaded distribute_setup.py

From DOS prompt navigated to python33 directory and did

```
python distribute_setup.py
```

Installed IPython using ipython-0.13.1.py3-win-amd64-PROPER (I right clicked and chose "run as administrator")

When I run IPython now I get the message "Warning: Realine services not available or not loaded. WARNING: Proper color port under MS Windows requires the pyreadline library."

What gives?

EDIT: I spent about three hours this evening trying to install python3 and Ipython with no success. I've read several SO threads and the IPython documentation pertaining to installing on Windows... still no success. If someone wants to write down how to get the right that would be very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully installed IPython 0.13.1 on a Windows 7 Professional 32-bit computer.  So let me share with you how I did it.

1. Install Python 3.3

   - Install to default folder:  C:\Python33
2. Install distribute

   - Download distribute:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute
   - Extract to: C:\distribute
   - At the command prompt:  navigate to C:\distribute
   - Run on command line:  `C:\Python33\python distribute_setup.py`
3. Install pyreadline

   - Download pyreadline:  https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline
   - Click on "ZIP" to download a zip file of PyReadline repository
   - Extract to C:\pyreadline
   - At the command prompt:  navigate to C:\pyreadline
   - Run this:  `C:\Python33\python setup.py install`
4. Install pygments and pyzmq

   - At the command prompt:  navigate to C:\Python33\Scripts
   - Run this:  `easy_install pygments pyzmq`
5. Download and install the next 3:

   - ZeroMq:  http://www.zeromq.org
   - PySide:  http://www.pyside.org
   - IPython:  http://www.ipython.org
6. Launch IPython

   - There should be a Start Menu shortcut
   - Start Menu > All Programs > IPython > IPythonQT

Comment: The above instructions pertain to Python 3.3.  If you want to install Python 2.7.3, just ignore step 3 and modify step 4 to `easy_install pygments pyzmq pyreadline`.

Comment: Note that step 3 gets an older version of pyreadline than using `pip install` does - PyPI is on version 2.1, yet github has only 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development release of pyreadline (it's [on Github](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline)). Python 3 support has been added since 1.7.1.

You might want to look at [Pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/), an all-in-one scientific Python 3 distribution that includes IPython. That's probably the easiest way to get started. There are several similar distributions based on Python 2, but Pyzo is the first one to try with Python 3.