# Warning on starting cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

The following warning appears every time I start cqlsh:

> WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing.  Install to enable tab completion.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It would help if you included which version of cassandra you were using, what operating system you were on, whether you have tried installing the pyreadline package and any other useful information that would help us answer this.

Comment: Maybe try: pip install pyreadline

Comment: I installed but still it is giving the warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install pyreadline for DataStax Cassandra

```
Set PATH variable for Python to
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python


1.     Download pyreadline: https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline
2.     Click on "ZIP" to download a zip file of PyReadline repository
3.     Extract to C:\pyreadline
4.     At the command prompt: navigate to C:\pyreadline
5.     Run this: C:\pyreadline\python setup.py install
```

This will update the Python distribution bundled with Datastax Community Edition.

Answer (score 2):

What version are you running, it looks like this has been fixed in a fairly low version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7749

I would guess that most likely you are running on windows in which case just follow this here: [ipython on Windows 7 can't find pyreadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583458/ipython-on-windows-7-cant-find-pyreadline)

If this is not the case simply go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline/ and follow install instructions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i am using cassandra 3.9 on windows 10. i have installed the pyreadline but still getting this warning.

Comment: oh, sorry to hear that :( I don't know my way around windows that good, would restart help?