# WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing. Install to enable tab completion

Tags: windows, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra Version: 2.2.3 in windows 10. When I cqlsh command in the prompt I get the following -

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.3 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing.  Install to enable tab completion.
```

I have installed pyreadline using `pip install pyreadline` and it installed successfully.

I have restarted the system as well but couldn't get rid of that warning.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703631/warning-on-starting-cqlsh

Comment: I had gone through that thread before posting my question. But the solution didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding your python to your PATH environment variable. Maybe thats why you may be having that problem.